# Hide loading icon after 3 sec, when we click on a link <a

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a loading icon in CSS, when someone clicks on a link the problem is in the mobile version I have a slide menu that open with one tag, or link, and the CSS icon is showing and never disappear.

I need to hide the CSS icon after 3 sec, this is my code.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
     $('.loadingDiv').fadeIn('slow', function(){
               $('.loadingDiv').delay(3000).fadeOut(); 
            });
   $('<div class="loadingDiv mobileShow"></div>').prependTo(document.body); 
});
```

```css
.loadingDiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 45%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: .5;
    width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;

  margin: 100px auto;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }
}

@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 50% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 100% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

But is not working, any help will be great, because the

Comment: Well, that snippet won't do anything, since there's no HTML defined, and jQuery hasn't been included in it.

Comment: $('<div class="loadingDiv mobileShow"></div>').prependTo(document.body);

Comment: [edit] your question with a minimal example. See [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget about [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

You can simply:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  ... do the fading out here ...
}, 3000);
```

I always prefer vanila-js solution over jQuery one. ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I resolve the issue, this is my code in JS   '<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function(){
     $('.loadingDiv').fadeIn('slow', function(){
               $('.loadingDiv').delay(2000).fadeOut(); 
            });
    /*$('<div class="loadingDiv mobileShow" id="loadingDiv" style="display:none;"></div>').prependTo(document.body); */
});
</script>
<div class="loadingDiv" id="loadingDiv" style="display:none;"></div>'